# Nest API Integration - Authorization Error 400

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, nest

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to manually give Nest permissions and get authorization-code I but keep getting "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch"
This is the URL I used (I replaced project-id and oauth2-client-id with my credentials)

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gjhE.png)

[Screenshot 2 - error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNK8u.png)

This is the instructions I have been following:
https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's not code. I'm just trying to enter get authorization-code, using this URL that google provide: https://www.google.com?code=authorization-code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sdm.service

Comment: I'm trying to manually approve this integration in the browser